# Websphere 8.5.5.13 MDB fails to connect to local queue

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have an EJB3 application that successfully runs locally on my Windows server. I have set it up in Azure Windows server along with MQ75 installation exactly as I have on my local machine.
The application fails to start with the following error. I have verified that the queue DOMAIN_UPDATE is in fact a local queue on Queue manager QM_azure. But for some reason, Websphere MDB deployment thinks that is is not local.

Any help is appreciated.

```
[6/11/18 16:22:28:514 UTC] 00000048 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0180I: The DomainUpdateMessageBean message-driven bean in the PatternSpyProcessor.jar module of the PatternSpyEngine application is bound to the jms/ActConfigDomainUpdate activation specification.
[6/11/18 16:22:30:822 UTC] 00000048 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: MQJCA4023: Startup reconnection failed for ActivationSpec 'javax.jms.Queue:jms/DOMAIN_UPDATE@QM_azure <-1480355656>'. Exception details: '
                       Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1017: non-local MQ queue 'DOMAIN_UPDATE' not valid for receiving or browsing.
The MQ queue is not able to be opened, as it is not local to the connected Queue Manager. 
Connect to the Queue Manager for which this MQ Queue resides locally.
                         Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:580)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:124)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:988)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:821)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnectionBrowser.<init>(WMQConnectionBrowser.java:1391)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createConnectionBrowser(WMQConnection.java:858)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createConnectionBrowser(JmsConnectionImpl.java:1038)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.createConnectionBrowser(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:235)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.<init>(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.<init>(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:111)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createConnectionConsumer(JmsConnectionImpl.java:437)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createConnectionConsumer(MQConnection.java:206)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.createConnectionConsumer(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:650)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDeliveryASF(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:391)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDelivery(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:334)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:234)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:408)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateUnderRAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:647)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:363)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(RAWrapperImpl.java:1120)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1803)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint(MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.java:168)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4726)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startMDBs(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:686)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:701)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:338)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3588)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5464)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
                               : com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
     Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2045' ('MQRC_OPTION_NOT_VALID_FOR_TYPE').
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:124)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:988)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:821)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnectionBrowser.<init>(WMQConnectionBrowser.java:1391)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createConnectionBrowser(WMQConnection.java:858)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createConnectionBrowser(JmsConnectionImpl.java:1038)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.createConnectionBrowser(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:235)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.<init>(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.<init>(JmsConnectionConsumerImpl.java:111)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createConnectionConsumer(JmsConnectionImpl.java:437)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createConnectionConsumer(MQConnection.java:206)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.createConnectionConsumer(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:650)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDeliveryASF(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:391)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDelivery(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:334)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:234)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:408)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateUnderRAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:647)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:363)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(RAWrapperImpl.java:1120)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1803)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint(MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.java:168)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4726)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startMDBs(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:686)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:701)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:338)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3588)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5464)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
                               : com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
                               : com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
                               : com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Display queue details:

```
     1 : dis q(DOMAIN_UPDATE)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(DOMAIN_UPDATE)                    TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2017-09-02)
   ALTTIME(12.07.42)                       BOQNAME( )
   BOTHRESH(0)                             CLUSNL( )
   CLUSTER( )                              CLCHNAME( )
   CLWLPRTY(0)                             CLWLRANK(0)
```

Comment: Is the queue type `QLOCAL`, the error indicates you are trying to read from a `QREMOTE` or a `QALIAS` which resolves to a remotely clustered `QLOCAL`, neither of these is possible.  Can you provide the output of `DIS Q(DOMAIN_UPDATE) TYPE`

Comment: Below is the output of display q command showing it is a QLOCAL.

Comment: dis q(DOMAIN_UPDATE)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(DOMAIN_UPDATE)                    TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2017-09-02)
   ALTTIME(12.07.42)                       BOQNAME( )
   BOTHRESH(0)                             CLUSNL( )
   CLUSTER( )                              CLCHNAME( )
   CLWLPRTY(0)                             CLWLRANK(0)

Comment: Not you can't format in comments so it is better to put in the question by selecting edit and adding it.  You can format in monospace (code block) by highting what you paste in edit mode and clicking the `{}` icon.  I have added this to your question.

Comment: Are you sure that the connection factory is pointing to the same queue manager where you ran the `DIS Q` command (`QM_azure`)?  Is it possible you have a CF that also points to the queue manager which has the `QREMOTE` and you are connecting in error to that queue manager or that your CF has the wrong host name and you are getting directed to another queue manager?  Check out this answer "[JMS MQ binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794667/jms-mq-binding-problem)

Comment: Thanks JoshMC. There is only one queue connection factory which connects to the queue manager QM_azure which has the local queue DOMAIN_UPDATE. I have rechecked all configuration setup. I have used similar setup successfully many times on local servers. I have also read through the 'JMS MQ binding problem' link. I am suspecting something in the way Azure Windows server is resolving network connectivity from WebSphere built-in MQ client to the queue  manager.

Comment: I would suggest doing a JMS and a Qmgr trace and reviewing them or opening a PMR with IBM, although with out extended support agreement you would not be able to do that with 7.5 which went out of support at the end of April.